# Work-around for IE7 to wrap text when hasLayout applied

Tags: html, css, haslayout

Is there a work-around for the known IE7 issue where text does not wrap around floating elements when the text's container has hasLayout applied (in this case, due to the height, which is required)?

For example:

```
<div style="width:200px;">
    <div style="float:right; width:50px; height:100px; background:#ff0;">&nbsp;</div>
    <div style="background:#0ff; height:400px;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

- Create a placeholder element for each line
- Set `float:left; clear:left; overflow:hidden;` and a generic height for every placeholder
- Set a specific width for each placeholder

Here is an example:

```
#holdit em {display:block; float:left; height:18px; overflow:hidden; clear:left;}
.a230 {width:230px;}
.a240 {width:240px;}
.a250 {width:250px;}
.a270 {width:270px;}
.a300 {width:300px;}
.a340 {width:340px;}
.a360 {width:360px;}
.a370 {width:370px;}
.a400 {width:400px;}
.a420 {width:420px;}
.a430 {width:430px;}
.a460 {width:460px;}
.a490 {width:490px;}
.a500 {width:500px;}
.a540 {width:540px;}
.a550 {width:550px;}
```

**References**

- [Stu Nicholls | CSSplay | Wrapping text around images](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/embed.html)
- [Stu Nicholls | CSSplay | Tracking your images](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/flow.html)